# Processing/Dropdown menu

Tags: processing

Good Afternoon,

I was hoping to find help on this website! I want to program a program that stores all necessary documents and pdf's for pilots. I am done with creating a background and adding the buttons, now I would like to create a on mouse over for all the five buttons. But how does this work?

```
void setup()
{
  size(1024,1024);
  PImage img;
  img = loadImage("Lufthansa.jpg");
  background(img);

Button Checklists = addButton("Checklists",20,40,100,50);
Button Flightplan = addButton("Flightplan",160,40,100,50);
Button Procedures = addButton("Procedures",300,40,100,50);
Button Airports = addButton("Airports",440,40,100,50);
Button Weather = addButton("Meteorology",580,40,100,50);
}
```

I appreciate your help, thank you !

Comment: Code you post should be in the form of an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Can you show us your `Button` class?

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "creating a on mouse over"? What exactly do you want to happen when the mouse goes over a button?

Comment: Hm, considered it obvious that 'Button' inherits from an awt button or a swing JButton and 'mouse over' meant some kind of hovering behaviour, i. e. some kind of highlighting the button as long as the mouse is over. Apparently isn't...